# Auto voice recognition in IOS

Tags: speech-recognition, speech

As per my app requirement,it should auto detect or recognise the user speech or voice.Can anyone just pass me the link which works fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should ask Google

Answer (score 2):

The OpenEars sample based on the PocketSphinx engine does a pretty good job with a small vocabulary:
[OpenEars](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2010/09/openears-speech-library-for-iphone-using-cmusphinx/)

Answer (score 1):

Try [Nuance SpeechKit for iOS](http://dragonmobile.nuancemobiledeveloper.com/public/index.php?task=home).
Now it is one of the best speech recognition services.